# Specifically Chrome issue to navigate when VPN connection is active - Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, vpn

This was never a problem until today: 
 Once VPN is established, Chrome becomes unusable and any link click results in:

```
The proxy http://[related_to_vpn_url_ending_with_DnsSuffix_in_VPN_settings]:8080 
requires a username and password. Your connection to this site is not private.

Username:

Password:
```

No problem in Internet Explorer or FireFox, but the same issue exists with Microsoft Edge, which is based on Chromium.

Once VPN is disconnected, Chrome is back to normal and "Reset and Clean up" in Chrome didn't make any difference.

- What could suddenly trigger this change in Chrome behaviour?
- What should be looked at, as Edge behaves the same and it's unlikely re-installing Chrome will help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case unchecking "Automatically detect settings" in "Local Area Network(LAN) Settings" fixed the problem.

> Control Panel > Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings.